# How to install gpxe/etherboot to hard disk

Tags: linux, pxe-boot

I have an old PC that I'd like to use as an [LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org/) client, but its BIOS cannot boot from the network... I tried booting from a CDROM containing a gxpe (Etherboot) image downloaded from [ROM-o-matic](http://rom-o-matic.net/) and it works, so my question is: how do I install the image directly to the local hard disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way:

1. Boot from a liveCD
2. Download USB image from ROM-o-matic
3. dd if=gpxe-1.0.1-gpxe.usb of=/dev/hda